# EL throws PropertyNotFoundException when method is static

Tags: java, jsf, el, propertynotfoundexception

Given the following JSF code: 
`<h:outputText value="#{bean.foo}" />`  
and proper method in my bean: 
`public String getFoo(){
    return "foo";
}` 
everything works just great. But when I switch my bean's method to static 
`public static String getFoo(){
    return "foo";
}` 
It does not work anymore, because EL throws an exception:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'bean' does not have the property 'foo'.

Why does the method must not be static?

Comment: can you try `#{Bean.foo}`?

Comment: I'm even more confused, because it works when I spell bean in CamelCase. Why does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making `foo` static it no longer fits into the definition of a `property` of this class. You can still call getFoo() directly, but it won't autowire this for you when constructed the way you've changed it